# Transfer Inheritance from US to a NRA in Indonesia

Tags: united-states, stocks, banking, non-resident, inheritance

I am a non resident alien, not living in the US. I inherited funds from a US stock exchange account after the owner died, but they could not wire it to a non US bank. THey can only wire to a US bank under my name, which I do not have. I can't open a bank account in the US in my name as they require SSN and what nots. Etransfers are also impossible. What options do I have?

Comment: So what brokerage is it? It's totally ok to state the name.

Answer (score 2):

> "but they could not wire it to a non US bank"

This is completely strange and bizarre.

They can and should send it anywhere you want. At worst - get a cheque.

Are you sure this isn't some scam?

Comment: No it is not a scam. The funds are still there. They say that due to FATCA, they have no collaboration with my country. I can get a check, but still would have to cash it in a US Bank, and they can't send abroad. I have seen others face the same problem. Like the following https://www.trade2win.com/threads/td-ameritrade-withdrawal-issues.142204/